# Intersection of n matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, intersection

I have a structure of high number n (3000, 5000...) of elements, each element is represented by matrices InputMat and OutputMat of different dimensions. I want to form groups where the elements of each group share AT THE SAME TIME a least one element in the InputMat AND time at least one element in the OutputMat.

For example

```
Element(1).InputMat=[22,12,36; 14,25,11]
Element(1).OutputMat=[18,77;44,82]

Element(2).InputMat=[7,63; 15,40,2,5]
Element(2).OutputMat=[17,60;30,54]

Element(3).InputMat=[35,12,99; 20,31]
Element(3).OutputMat=[90,18;8,77]

Element(4).InputMat=[22,12,36; 14,25,11]
Element(4).OutputMat=[54,17,120;81,16]
...

Element(n).InputMat=[63,40,44; 36,10]
Element(n).OutputMat=[18,77;17,34].
```

From this example I would have 3 groups:

- Group1= `{Element(1),Element(3)}` because they share the number 12 in InputMat and the numbers 77,18 in OutputMat.
- Group2= `{Element(2), Element(n)}` because they share the numbers 63,40 in InputMat and the number 17 in OutputMat.
- Group3= `{Element(4)}`

Group3 have one element which is Element(4) because Element(4) doesn't share the same time at least one element in inputMat and OutputMat with the other elements.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: You need to compare each of the matrices to all other matrices, a loop in a loop. It’s expensive computationally. What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 all share number 12, should there be a group with those three elements? Or is it always two elements to a group? Can an element be in multiple groups at the same time?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes I've tried to compare each matrice to others but with smal exmaple of maticies. I'am looking for a way to avoid the loops bcause its would be very expansive.

Comment: @CrisLuengo 1,2 and 4 sahare 12 in the InputMat but they don't have a commun elment in the outputMat so they can't be in the same group. A group can contain any  number of elmments 1,2, 3,4 ..... and No, an elment can't be in multiple group at the same time.

Comment: 1. What does `Group3= {Element(n)}` mean?
2. If you have 
`Element(1) = input[1 1; 1 1] with output[2 2; 2 2]`
`Element(2) = input[1 3; 3 3] with output[2 4; 4 4]`
`Element(3) = input[1 5; 5 5] with output[2 6; 6 6]`
what should be done with these elements (they all have 1 and 2)? Should they all be in one group? Or should there be three groups (1&2, 1&3, 2&3)? Or is this guaranteed never to happen?

Comment: 3. Also consider the example

`Element(4) = input[1 3; 3 3] with output[2 4; 4 4]`

`Element(5) = input[1 5; 5 5] with output[2 6; 6 6]`

`Element(6) = input[3 5; 5 5] with output[4 6; 6 6]`

How should this case be managed? Should they all be in the same group? Or should there be three groups (4&5, 4&6, 5&6)? Or is this guaranteed never to happen?

Comment: @magnesium sorryI did a mistake, Group3={Element(4)}. In the example you gave the elment 1&2&3 would be in the same group because they all share an elment in input and another in output.

Comment: @magnesium, for your secod example, it a spatial case that is not allowed for my wok  but I can manege it.  Two groups can be formed Group1={4&5} , Group2={5&6} and I shoose to keep only one.

Comment: "*I'm looking for a way to avoid loops because it would be very expensive.*" - Have you tried it? Regardless of whether you're looking for the maximum number of groups, or just taking a greedy approach, the time complexity is going to be *O(n^2\*m)* where *n* is the number of elements and *m* is the size of each matrix. How can `{Element(4)}` be a group by itself? Please add clarifications to the question itself using [edit].

Comment: @beaker I tried just a smal size example, The probelm is The size of groups can be diffrent !!, so I tried to find first all combination that can be formed by the elment's structure, then for each combination, I search If they share elemnts in the inputmat and Outputmat. Howver, this wil take me  a lot of time. Can you suggest me another way to do it?

Comment: As I said, you're going to have to compare (almost) all pairs of elements. You're not going to get around that part unless you know something about the values of in the arrays that would allow you to exclude some pairs. To perform the comparisons, I'd suggest looking at [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.intersect.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html). Either will do what you want, but you'll need to do some timings to see which one is faster.